# Why is file open in .NET Core Host?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have just upgraded from .NET Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.0.

I have a XUnitTest project with reference to my main project.

When rebuilding I get the follwing errors:

```
Could not copy "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\XXX.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\XXX.dll". 
Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: ".NET Core Host (2016)"  


Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\XXX.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\XXX.dll". 
The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Customer.Service.Tests.dll' because it is being used by another process.
```

I Have also tries to manually delete the bin folder, restarting VS 2019.
The only thing that "works" is to remove the refenece and restart the computer (win10)

Why is the file open in .NET Core Host(2016)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Swagger (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 4.0.1 does not support .NET Core 3.0
Version 5.0.0-rc3 does.

Comment: How did you find out that Swashbuckle.AspNetCore was the cause of your issues?